# How to handle options object sent by dc.beginDialog to other component dialog

Tags: node.js, botframework

In componentdialog A I have:

```
case '#trial': {
                return await step.beginDialog(LEAD_CAPTURE_DIALOG, { intent: '#trial' });
```

That starts componentdialog B

In componentdialog B I need the intent to 'customize' the dialog.

```
class LeadCaptureDialog extends ComponentDialog {
    constructor() {
        super(LEAD_CAPTURE_DIALOG);

        this.addDialog(new TextPrompt(NAME_PROMPT));
        this.addDialog(new WaterfallDialog(WATERFALL_DIALOG, [
            this.getNameStep.bind(this),
        ]));
        this.initialDialogId = WATERFALL_DIALOG;
    }
    async getNameStep(stepContext) {
        console.log(arguments[0]);
        await stepContext.context.sendActivity('Message varies based on the intent send in the options object in beginDialog');
        return await stepContext.prompt(NAME_PROMPT, 'What is your name?');
```

I only have the arguments object and the options object (with the intent) is indeed in there. I trust there must be a more efficient way to use the (optional) options object in beginDialog.
Does anyone know how?

Comment: I'm not quite sure how this would work in node.js but what I did in my C# app was to create a model/class that represented that data that I wanted to pass through. Inside the child dialog that read out the options I would then attempt to cast the options into an instance of the model, I could then use the model property names instead of indexing into properties. Are you able to clarify what you mean by "more efficient"?

Comment: Tnx for your suggestion. I ended up using this value in the arguments object': arguments[0]._info.options. This one seems to do the trick for my use-case. Not to sure thought because it is not documented as such.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is easier in Node than C#, since stepContext.options is just a JSON object and there's no typing (if you're using TypeScript, it's better to create an Interface, similar to the C# example below).

**Send The Intent to Your LEAD_CAPTURE_DIALOG**

```js
await stepContext.beginDialog(LEAD_CAPTURE_DIALOG, { intent: '#trial' });
```

**Capture it in `stepContext.options` of LEAD_CAPTURE_DIALOG**

```js
const intent = stepContext.options["intent"];
```

---

---

**C# Version, since I accidentally answered with this, first**

You have two options:

#### 1. Create a new Class/Model

(as @MattStannett suggested) This is the option likely considered "best practice".

**Create `MyObject.cs`**

```cs
namespace MyBot
{
    public class MyObject
    {
        public string Intent { get; set; }
    }
}
```

**Send The Intent to Your LEAD_CAPTURE_DIALOG**

```cs
await stepContext.BeginDialogAsync(LEAD_CAPTURE_DIALOG, new MyObject() { Intent = "#trial" });
```

**Capture it in `stepContext.Options` of LEAD_CAPTURE_DIALOG**

```cs
var intent = (stepContext.Options as MyObject).Intent;
```

#### 2. Use an Anonymous Object

```cs
await stepContext.BeginDialogAsync(LEAD_CAPTURE_DIALOG, new { Intent = "#trial" });
```

```cs
var intent = stepContext.Options.GetType().GetProperty("Intent").GetValue(stepContext.Options, null);

// OR with C#4+:

var intent = (stepContext.Options as dynamic).Intent;
```

Comment: Tnx. I’m on Node.js. Similar approach?

Comment: @Hessel Oh no! I even prefer Node. Just mixed up my response. Yes. Similar approach. I'll re-type it up

Comment: @Hessel, Updated with Node version

Comment: That is indeed more efficient :-) Beats searching and retrieving it from the arguments-thing. Thank you!

Comment: @Hessel It would've been more efficient if I had read you were using Node from the get-go ;)